# my php code don't work result

Tags: php, mysql

I have an issue in my php script when I enter a correct username it echo "user found" and when

I enter wrong user name it echo also "user found".

Here is my code please check and let me know, if !$result variable supposed to work but didn't. Why?.

```
<?php
    echo "enter the username \n";
    $username = trim(fgets(STDIN));
    echo "enter the password\n";
    $password = trim(fgets(STDIN));

    //connecting to database
    $db = mysql_connect("localhost","sqldata","sqldata") or die(mysql_error());

    //selecting our database
    $db_select = mysql_select_db("accounts", $db) or die(mysql_error());

    $result= mysql_query("select * from login where username = '$username' ");
    if (!$result)
    {
        echo "error no user";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "user found";
    }

    mysql_close($db)
?>
```

Comment: Please consider using a different mysql extension: http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_query` returns a result resource, unless there's an actual error in the MySQL query. This result gives absolutely no indication as to whether there are actually any rows in it.

Try this:

```
$result = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("select * from `login` where `username`='".mysql_real_escape_string($username)."'"));
if( !$result) echo "Error no user";
else echo "user found";
```

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using `mysql_*` functions as they are deprecated and will be removed.

To answer your question, the reason is because `mysql_query` returns a result object if the query executed successfully.

You need to use [`mysql_num_rows()`](http://php.net/mysql_num_rows) to check if the user was found or not.

```
$result = mysql_query("select * from login where username = '$username' ");

if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
    echo "error no user";
} else {
    echo "user found";
}
```

In addition, you should always check that the query did not fail like this:

```
if (!$result) {
    echo "Query failed!  Reason: " . mysql_error();
    exit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as the query actually executes (i.e. there is not a MySQL or query error) `if(!result)` will always validate as `true` even if 0 records were found. This is because `$result` is a MySQL result set resource, not a direct value from the query.

You need to check the number of rows returned:

```
$result= mysql_query("select * from login where username = '$username' ");

if(!$result) {
    echo "MySQL error: " . mysql_error();
} else if (mysql_num_rows($result) === 0) {
    echo "User not found";
} else {
    echo "user found";
}
```

I would also STRONGLY suggest you not use `mysql_*` functions they are deprecated adn should no longer be used. Perhaps look at `mysqli` or `PDO` instead.

Answer (score 0):

YOu will get a result object back even if no rows were matched. You need to see how many rows the result returned; check out https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php.

Also, I highly recommend that as long as you're learning how to do the queries, use mysqli rather than mysql. It's better in every way.